# Set up a button to switch between Capital letters and small letters in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, button

Hi guys really needing a bit of help on this one. Im wanting to use 1x Button that has 2x Functions. I believe the answer if some kind of IF Statement but unsure how to carry it out. Im wanting the user to press a button that will change images on the screen. Then when it is pressed again it is reverted back to its original images.

---

Currently doing it with two buttons (switch)  and the other is (switchback) as seen below

```
    // Button changes the letter images to Small Letters from Capital Letters
            btnswitchback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnswitchback);
            btnswitchback.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // When user clicks button it Changed each letter to small case
                    buttona.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a);
                }
            });

    // Button changes the letter images to Small Letters from Capital Letters
            btnswitch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnswitch);
            btnswitch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // When user clicks button it Changed each letter to small case
                    buttona.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.aa);
                }
            });
```

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use a flag and set it to true when it is clicked.. and change the image the first time, the second time if it sees the flag as true change the image again ... and then set the flag to false.

Comment: You can try http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-togglebutton-example/ Toggle Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine which button has been clicked on like this if you don't want repeated code:

```
Button btnSwitchBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnswitchback);
Button btnSwitch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnswitch);

OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnswitchback:
            // switch back button clicked
            // do stuff here
            break;
        case R.id.btnswitch:
            // switch button clicked
            // do other stuff here
            break;
        }
    }
};

btnSwitch.setOnClickListener(listener);
btnSwitchBack.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: I used this and it worked perfectly, thank you for your quick promt answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple way you can do this using same button. Set a flag and switch it accordingly.

```
Int click = 0;

btnswitch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnswitch);
            btnswitch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // When user clicks button it Changed each letter to small case
                   if(click == 0){
                     click = 1;
                    buttona.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a);
                    }
                  if(click == 1){
                     click = 0;
                    buttona.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.aa);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Otherwise you can use [ToggleButtons](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html)  in android.

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // The toggle is enabled
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your quick promt answer, i tested this and toggle was also an option but im going to save it for futuer as its great example so thank you

Comment: I have used toggle button as setting the click runs straight into the next if condition without the user pressing the same button again.